# Find consecutive capitalized words in a string, including apostrophes

Tags: python, regex, findall, apostrophe, capitalization

I am using regex to find all instances of consecutive words that are both capitalized, and where some of the consecutive words contain an apostrophe, ie ("The mother-daughter bakery, Molly’s Munchies, was founded in 2009"). And I have written a few lines of code to do this:

```
string = "The mother-daughter bakery, Molly’s Munchies, was founded in 2009"
test = re.findall("([A-Z][a-z]+(?=\s[A-Z])(?:\s[A-Z][a-z]+)+)", string)
print(test)
```

The issue is I am unable to print the result ('Molly's Munchies')

Instead my output is:

```
('[]')
```

Desired output:

```
("Molly's Munchies")
```

Any help appreciated, thank you!

Comment: `re.findall(r"(?!^)\b[A-Z][a-z]+(?:'s?)?(?:\s+[A-Z][a-z]+(?:'s?)?)+", string)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this regex in python:

```
r"\b[A-Z][a-z'’]*(?:\s+[A-Z][a-z'’]*)+"
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/NYhskl/3)

**RegEx Details:**

- `\b`: Word match
- `[A-Z]`: Match a capital letter
- `[a-z'’]*`: Match 0 or more characters containing lowercase letter or `'` or `’`
- `(?:\s+[A-Z][a-z'’]*)+` Match 1 or more such capital letter words

Comment: Hi Anubhava thanks for your comment, I realized that I made a small mistake in the example string I gave. Instead my string is ""The Cow goes moo and the Dog's Name, is orange", where there is no whitespace after the second capitalized word (Name). How can make this stipulation in the regex code? Thanks

Comment: Even if there is no whitespace after `Name` it will still match `Dog's Name`. You can check demo: https://regex101.com/r/NYhskl/2 also

Comment: Interesting,  I see that with the comma your code is still correct, but and I am sorry for the confusion,  I was only trying to create a similar example, the real string I am using for my project is "The mother-daughter bakery, Molly’s Munchies, was founded in 2009". I had tried to create an example similar to this, and thought maybe the comma was the issue. However the code is not working with this string, any ideas?

Comment: It is because your apostrophe character is `’` instead of `'` so you can use: https://regex101.com/r/NYhskl/3

Comment: Thank you for your commitment to helping, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to add it in both places you define a "word".  You only added it in one place.

```
string = "The Cow goes moo, and the Dog's Name is orange"
# e.g. both                here                    and here
#                           v                           v
print(re.findall("([A-Z][a-z']+(?=\s[A-Z])(?:\s[A-Z][a-z']+)+)", string))
['The Cow', "Dog's Name"]
```

Comment: Hi Cireo, you and Anubhava were both very quick, and thank you for your comment, I realized that I made a small mistake in the example string I gave. Instead my string is ""The Cow goes moo and the Dog's Name, is orange", where there is no whitespace after the second capitalized word (Name). How can make this stipulation in the regex code? Thanks